# Como otimizar essa query de consulta com outras subconsultas?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Tenho uma query de consulta que está demorando um tempo excessivo para ser executada (quase 2min) e preciso otimizá-la:

```sql
select Cidade.Id as CidadeId, Cidade.Nome as CidadeNome, 
       Cargo.Descricao as CargoDescricao, '{0}' as Grupo, Count(*) as Qtd
from Funcionario
inner join Cargo on Cargo.Id = Funcionario.CargoId
inner join Bairro on Bairro.Id = Funcionario.BairroId
inner join Cidade on Cidade.Id = Bairro.CidadeId
inner join FuncionarioHistorico on FuncionarioHistorico.Id in (
    select Top 1 FuncionarioHistorico.Id from FuncionarioHistorico FH
    where FH.FuncionarioId = Funcionario.Id
      and FH.EmpresaId = Funcionario.EmpresaId
      and year(FH.DataRegistro) = @AnoBase
      and FH.TipoHistoricoId = @TipoHistoricoId
      and FH.Id not in ( select NP.Id from FuncionarioHistorico NP
                         where NP.FuncionarioId = Funcionario.Id
                           and NP.EmpresaId = Funcionario.EmpresaId
                           and NP.DataRegistro >= FH.DataRegistro
                           and year(NP.DataRegistro) = year(FH.DataRegistro)
                           and NP.TipoHistoricoId in ({2}) )
    order by FH.DataRegistro desc )
inner join TipoHistorico on TipoHistorico.Id = FuncionarioHistorico.TipoHistoricoId
where Funcionario.EmpresaId = @EmpresaId
  and Cargo.Id <> @CargoId
  and Cidade.Id in ( {1} )
  and Cidade.Uf = @Uf
group by Cidade.Id, Cidade.Nome, Cargo.Descricao
order by Cidade.Nome
```

**Modelo das tabelas**:

[image: Modelo]

**Execution Plain**:
**Obs: Tem alguma outra forma de obter o *Execution Plain*? Em formato texto eu tive problemas para postar aqui!**

[image: Execution Plain]

Essa consulta consistem em agrupar a quantidade de **Funcionários**, que possuem um determinado **Histórico**, por seus **Cargos** em cada **Cidade**. Porém, ela necessita ser filtrada por:

1. **Empresa** (`where Funcionario.EmpresaId = @EmpresaId`);
2. **Estado** (`and Cidade.Uf = @Uf`);
3. **Cidades** que serão pesquisadas (`and Cidade.Id in ( {1} )`) - **esse `{1}` é uma string que será alterada pela lista de `Ids` das cidades desejadas**.

E tem também algumas condições a serem observadas sobre o **Histórico** de cada **Funcionário** que entrará na contagem:

1. É por um **Tipo de Histórico** específico (`and FH.TipoHistoricoId = @TipoHistoricoId`);
2. O **Funcionário** precisará ter o **Tipo de Histórico** informado no **Ano** que deseja-se efetuar a pesquisa (`and year(FH.DataRegistro) = @AnoBase`);

   - Por isso da subconsulta que obtém o Id do último registro de histórico do **Funcionário** com o **Tipo de Histórico** desejado e o **Ano Base**.
3. Por fim, e também o motívo pela segunda subconsulta, é que o Funcionário não poderá ter nenhum dos outros Tipos de Histórico que serão informados após o Tipo de Histórico que se procura nele. Um Exemplo: O Funcionário não poderá ter o **Tipo de Histórico** "Transferido" após se pesquisar nele o **Tipo de Histórico** "Cargo Alterado".

**Essa é toda a questão e lhes pergunto o que poderia ser feito para otimizar o tempo de resposta da consulta?**

Comment: Postar a estrutura das tabelas e o Execution Plan com certeza ajudará :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR**

O que pode melhorár o desempenho da query:

- Remoção de `ORDER BY` desnecessários;
- Uso de campo indexados nos filtros do `WHERE`;
- Não utilizar funções no `WHERE` (`year()`, `month()`) para comparações de campos.

---

De acordo com o Execution Plan, os maiores vilões da sua query são os `sorts`. Só eles são responsáveis por 40% do tempo da execução da sua query.

Algumas ações que podem otimizar sua query:

- Na linha `inner join FuncionarioHistorico on FuncionarioHistorico.Id in ( SubQuery )` essa subquery retorna somente um resultado? Logo você pode alterar a comparação para simplesmente:

  ```
  inner join FuncionarioHistorico on FuncionarioHistorico.Id = ( SubQuery )
  ```
- O Filtro mais externo de estado ao meu ver pode ser eliminado. Se você já tem a lista de cidades, pressuponho que o estado já foi selecionado anteriormente.

  ```
  where Funcionario.EmpresaId = @EmpresaId
    and Cargo.Id <> @CargoId
    and Cidade.Id in ( {1} )
  ```
- O uso de funções no `WHERE` simplesmente ignora os índices do campos. Experimente uma abordagem diferente no lugar do `year(FH.DataRegistro) = @AnoBase`
- Verifique se os índices de sua tabela estão em ordem. O ideal é que todos os campos onde você faz os joins possuam índice.

Comment: Verdade, não tinha reparado nisso. Corrigido.